# Comparing two datetimes to check for a clash but seems to be confusing MM/DD with DD/MM C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, string, datetime

I am trying to check my database for a clash, I am reading up using a reader and calling the value down. My value is `10/12/2018 15:00:00` So I have stored this as `@moduleStartTime`

My next query checks the database using the above datetime and if it is between any other dates entered.

The issue I am encountering is that there are no clashes, so this shouldn't flag up that there are. I have found that the clash it is returning has a datetime of `12/10/2018 15:00:00`

It appears as though somewhere in the search, it is reversing DD/MM

Here is my code

```
//Reading to get all modules student is enrolled on 
string checkclash = "SELECT * FROM cModuleTimes INNER JOIN cStudentModule ON cModuleTimes.ModuleID = cStudentModule.ModuleID WHERE cStudentModule.StudentID=@studentid AND @date BETWEEN[StartTime] AND[EndTime] AND ModTimeID <> @modtimeid";

SqlCommand myCommandclash = new SqlCommand(checkclash, myConnectionclash);

myCommandclash.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", moduleStartTime);
myCommandclash.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseid", courseid);
myCommandclash.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", user);
myCommandclash.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modtimeid", moduletocompareid);

//create a sqldatareader object that asks for dats from a table
SqlDataReader rdrreadclash = myCommandclash.ExecuteReader();

if (rdrreadclash.HasRows)
{
    while (rdrreadclash.Read())
    {
        string getname = rdrreadclash["ModTimeID"].ToString();
        string gettime = rdrreadclash["StartTime"].ToString();
        Warning.Text = "There appears to be a clash with this event..<br><br> <br> <b>Would you like to continue?</b> <br><br>";

    }
    ViewClash.Visible = true;
    YesContinue.Visible = true; 
    FinishMod.Visible = false;
}
myConnectionclash.Close();
```

I have tried a couple of conversions but am receiving an issue with string not recognised as a DateTime.

If anyone has any answers on how I would prevent this clash from appearing, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the datatype of `moduleStartTime`?

Comment: u mean u have issues with the `sqlCommand` ?

Comment: It is currently a string, so I may need to convert it to datetime to the other format and back into string for comparsion? Thank you for looking into this for me. I am fairly new to C#

Comment: Don't convert your dates to strings.  Compare the dates themselves.

Comment: I'll give that a go Erik

Comment: Thank you Erik, that worked perfectly. You have saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

`moduleDateTime` is currently a string, you need to parse it in to a `DateTime` object where the parsing operation has the proper MM/DD order you want.

```
DateTime dateAsDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(moduleStartTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
myCommandclash.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateAsDateTime);
```

You then must format the returned date time back to a string in the format you want.

```
 string gettime = ((DateTime)rdrreadclash["StartTime"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss ");
```

Comment: `"parse it to a DateTime object that has the proper MM/DD order you want"` makes no sense, because real DateTime objects don't have any inherent MM/DD order at all. You can parse _from_ a specific datetime string format, and render to a string with a specific format, but you can't parse to a datetime where the datetime has any specific human-readable format at all.

Comment: It was bad grammar, a better way of saying it would be "parse it to a DateTime object **where the parsing operation** has the proper MM/DD order you want"